# Ubuntu 16.014 VM Server no network interface

Tags: networking, server, virtualization

I am doing a fresh install on one of my Dell ESX server, the servers are using a static setup.

I tried to use DHCP to configure the network during the install which failed so I set it up later.

When I went to add the gig0 interface to the interfaces file I tried to restart the networking service but it just does nothing but error out. It's like it totally forgot about the hardware being installed.
Screen shot attached, what am I doing wrong here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by vm server? what is your configuration?

Comment: doesn't look like you have gig0.  Post your `ifconfig -a`